# SQL order by 0 first and then descend number/values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a weird situation where i need to order 0 first and then descends a column.

Let's say i have column that looks like this

```
Status
------
3
4
0
5
1
2
4
0
2
```

And Now i need to order it by

```
Status
------
0
0
5
4
4
3
2
2
1
```

Is this possible for SQL? I've been trying to test for 2 days now but i am stuck.

Comment: mysqli is for MySQL, not for SQL Server. Moreover mysqli is for PHP to invoke SQL commands. What would that have to do with your question? Please only tag SQL and the DBMS, i.e. either SQL Server or MySQL, definitely not mysqli.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a `case` expression to first sort 0's and then the rest. After that sort by status desc:

```
order by case when Status = 0 then 0 else 1 end, status desc
```

Comment: Although there's no practical difference, I'd prefer `order by case when status = 0 then 1 else 0 end desc`, by analogy with the other condition.